# how do i maniputate table rows appended to an existing table in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have appended table rows with input elements to an existing table as follows:

```
$("#additems_table").append(
"<tr><td style='color:#999; font-size:16px;'>"+(counter++)+"</td><td>
<select class='item'><?php while($product_rows=mysql_fetch_assoc($productSQL)){?><option value='<?php echo $product_rows['pid']; ?>'><?php echo $product_rows['name']; ?></option><?php }?></select></td><td id='quantity_td'><input name='quantity' class='quantity' type='text' style='width:35px' id='cost"+(numqty++)+"' /><input type='hidden' name='price_hf' id='cost"+(numprice++)+"'/></td><td id='amount_td'><input name='amount' id='cost"+(numamount++)+"' style='width:70px' type='text' value='3' disabled='disabled'/></td></tr>");
});
```

The problem come in when i try to manipulate these elements within the above appended rows.It simply does not listen to any event, click, change, etc. e.g

```
$("#additems_table input[type=text]").each(function(){
    $(this).change(function(){          
        alert("amount");
    });
})
```

I will really appreciate the help.

Comment: Please can you post a formatted code sample and ideally the code that is passed to the browser, not a mix of jQuery and php.

Comment: I suspect that a jQuery live event is what you need. See: http://jqapi.com/docs/live/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, to wire up the new input elements do something along the lines of:

```
$(function(){

    $('#additems_table input[type="text"]').live('change', function(){

    });
});
```

What that means is: on load create a global handler for the change event of all elements that are inside the `#additems_table`. The live method makes it possible to create new elements (input textboxes) on the fly without having to worry about their event registration. The `change` event of the newly appended elements will fire and will be handled automatically.